# openedx - devstack installation error: bower not found

Tags: bower, devstack, openedx

I tried to install the openedx devstack using dogwood.3 release.
In the provision steps I get this error:

**default: stderr: /bin/sh: 1: /edx/app/programs/programs/node_modules/.bin/bower: not found**

here's the steps I followed:

```
curl -L https://raw.github.com/edx/configuration/master/vagrant/release/devstack/Vagrantfile > Vagrantfile
vagrant plugin install vagrant-vbguest
export OPENEDX_RELEASE="named-release/dogwood.3"
vagrant up
```

The vm is up but I can't start any service.

any idea please?

Regards,

Comment: where can I find the full log file?
the log on the console is cut off.
Regards,

Comment: Maybe you can try the ironwood version now